# How to I make my IOS app play music in the background forever?

Tags: ios, iphone, background

I want to write a music player iOS app that plays music in a loop in the background. I do not want the music to stop. Also, I want to run a timer that executes updates every once in a while that might change the music played.

- When I try to write this app, the music eventually stops playing after sometime. Additionally, I notice that the iTunes Player has the same behavior. If I set iTunes to loop indefinitely on some song, and let it play, within some amount of hours the music will stop.

I have setup my app for "audio" background exectution and I have code like this to start playing audio:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)  
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)  
let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)  
player.numberOfLoops = -1  
player.prepareToPlay()  
player.delegate = self  
player.play()  

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {  
  player.play()  
}
```

Why does iOS kill my app and make it stop playing music and running my Timer?

Comment: Can you check if you are getting some errors. Reading [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayback) looks like if another active audio session has higher priority than yours (for example, a phone call), and neither audio session allows mixing, attempting to activate your audio session fails. Deactivating an audio session that has running audio objects will stop the running audio objects, deactivate the session, and a AVAudioSessionErrorCodeIsBusy error will be returned.

Comment: Is your audio in the app getting paused sometimes or app is getting killed? Because youtube red has this functionality to play in background for ever so i reckon it should be possible for our app to do so. But yes, as @todor mentioned when another audio like call comee it takes priority.

Comment: I've set my code to mixing. Also. iOS kills the app even if the phone is doing nothing else but playing music.

Comment: @gregm how we allow to play music from any music app from background simultaneously  when we open our app and our app also using AVAudioPlayer or AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID

Comment: @gregm when I open my app , music from background app stopped.
below solutions is not working for me [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
guys any suggestion help?

above solution is working when we do not use  any AVAudioPlayer or AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID

Answer (score 2):

Use MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller?language=objc

Comment: How is the system music player different?

Comment: AVAudioSession is attached to your app. iOS wont allow background execution unless it is for playing music. system music player is maintained by iOS